# CSP safe usage of 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: javascript, security, web, frontend

I'm backend developer helping with a web server deployment for a frontend team, while I was researching vulnerabilites I came across Content Security Policy, if I set up the CSP header this "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' data: {own_domain_1} {own_domain_2}", the website doesn't work, the frontend team tells me that adding 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' will not pose a threat since the domains where the data is being loaded from are our own but I have not come across any kind of documentation that make that claim, is it true?, and if not, can you point me to the documentation so I can bring it to my superiors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval basically renders your CSP useless to protect against JavaScript and CSS XSS attacks. Mozilla observatory is a great place to test and learn about security headers in general. https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze/klu.io , just replace "klu.io" with your domain name. After running the test it will tell you how to improve and why, I would imagine it is all the ammunition you need to persuade them to implement things properly. I will warn you, it takes a bit of doing to get a score over 100 (as you get bonus points up to 135 / 100).

Comment: My site uses inline scripts and CSS for performance reasons so if you view the source of my site (https://klu.io) you will see they use a "nonce" on the script and style tags, removing the need for `unsafe-inline`, hopefully it is a useful example for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely better if you can avoid unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval.

The usual cause for seeing/needing unsafe-inline is having inline styles or style tags on the page. Move all that to your css files and use only classes.

And unless there is an *EXTREMELY STRONG CASE FOR IT*, you should not permit unsafe-eval. And even if you find this extremely strong case, you should ask yourself whether this feature is truly necessary.

Both of these open serious vulnerabilities, not just from 3rd party users, but from your own employees - don't just trust 'em because they tell you to. Script injection is a serious security concern.

Comment: Great answer +1, just to add even if you must have inline style and script tags on a page you can reduce the risks with nonces and hashes as part of your CSP. https://www.troyhunt.com/locking-down-your-website-scripts-with-csp-hashes-nonces-and-report-uri/

Comment: Thanks for your input.